# Heap Buffer Overflow when assigning array in C

Tags: c

I want to malloc an array, but I get a heap overflow error when trying to do so. I have tried to find a solution but I could not figure it out. Here is my code:

```c
typedef struct scaledFootrule {
    double minTotalSFR;
    int *tempPermutation;
} SFR;

static SFR *sfrStruct(int urlSize) {
    SFR *sfr = malloc(sizeof(SFR *));
    if (sfr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: out of memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sfr->minTotalSFR     = MAX_TOTAL_SFR_DIST;
    sfr->tempPermutation = malloc((sizeof(int)) * urlSize);    
    return sfr;
}
```

When running, it gives this error:

> ==1646450==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000198 at pc 0x0000004c8d21 bp 0x7ffe39cd42b0 sp 0x7ffe39cd42a8
> WRITE of size 8 at 0x602000000198 thread T0

Thanks, and sorry if the solution is trivial.

Comment: `SFR *sfr = malloc(sizeof(SFR *));` => `SFR *sfr = malloc( sizeof( SFR ) );`

Comment: @AviBerger Why do you not consider that an answer? A little explanation might even make it a good one.

Comment: It's basically just a typo, the later "malloc((sizeof(int)) * urlSize);" suggests to me that the OP understands it - though overlooked it, and I should be getting to bed.

Comment: the problem is simple: you are asking to allocate a `SFR *` that can contain a `SFR *` which is obviously impossible

Answer (score 1):

**Correctness**

`SFR *sfr = malloc(sizeof(SFR *));` is an insufficient allocation.

Avoid allocation type mistakes.  Allocate to the referenced object, not the type.

```
//                   v-----------v    This is the size of a pointer 
// SFR *sfr = malloc(sizeof(SFR *));
SFR *sfr = malloc(sizeof sfr[0]);
//                ^-----------^ This is the size of one object.
```

**Review**

Consider the next case.  It it right?  To review, we need to find the `sfr` definition and then the `SFR` definition, wherever they may be, perhaps another file.  By using the referenced object size, code becomes easier to review.

```
// sfr->tempPermutation = malloc((sizeof(int)) * urlSize); 
sfr->tempPermutation = malloc(sizeof sfr->tempPermutation[0] * urlSize);
```

**Maintenance**

Suppose `.tempPermutation` no longer points to an `int`, but a `long long`.  By coding to the size of the referenced object and not type, no changes needed in the allocations.  Easier to maintain than coding in the type.